# Is it possible to duplicate a Trello board, including all comments, checklist, attachments etc..?

Tags: trello

Is it possible to duplicate a Trello board, including all comments, checklist, attachments etc.. ?

I know i am able to copy a board, which gives me all of the cards, columns etc.. but does not seem to include all comments, checklist, attachments etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible *in one step*. It can be done  **by copying all *lists* of a board and then moving them to the new board**. This preserves all card activity (including comments) and attachments.

https://help.trello.com/article/802-copying-cards-lists-or-boards